# Python Decorators | How the arguments of a function pass through a wrapper function

Tags: python, decorator, wrapper, python-decorators

In this decorators [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FsAPt_9Bf3U) by Corey Schafer he said the display_info function wouldn't run because it takes two arguments but wrapper_function takes 0 arguments.

```
def decorator_function(original_function):
    def wrapper_function():
        print('wrapper executed this before {}'.format(original_function.__name__))
        return original_function()
    return wrapper_function


@decorator_function
def display():
    print('display function ran')


@decorator_function
def display_info(name, age):
    print('display_info ran with arguments({},{})'.format(name, age))

display_info('John', 25)
```

Then he adds *args and **kwargs to the wrapper function so it can take any number of arguments.

```
def decorator_function(original_function):
    def wrapper_function(*args,**kwargs):
        print('wrapper executed this before {}'.format(original_function.__name__))
        return original_function(*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapper_function


@decorator_function
def display():
    print('display function ran')


@decorator_function
def display_info(name, age):
    print('display_info ran with arguments({},{})'.format(name, age))

display_info('John', 25)
```

![2][3]
My question is how does the arguments of our original function(display_info) goes to the wrapper_function.

Why it's not enough to just pass the args and kwargs to the original function where we return it inside the wrapper function

Does it take the arguments from the decorator_function when the display_info was passed into it.

Answer (score 0):

The decorator is similar with making hamburger, the only different in hamburger is stuffing, but all the hamburger will have the bread on the top and bottom. You can image the stuffing is display_info and bread is the code inside wrapper_function except your customized function and decorator_function is the hamburger maker and all the wrapper_function is the hamburger.

After display_info function add a decorator on it, it's essentially become wrapper_function. *args and **kwargs can be more flexibility for input parameter

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood when a decorator decorates a function it declares a new variable with the same name as the function that will be decorated

Ex:

```
@decorator_function
def display_info(name, age):
    print('display_info ran with arguments({},{})'.format(name, age))
```

The above translates to:

```
display_info = decorator_function(display_info)
```

At this stage 'decorater_function' is able to access the function that will be decorated, keep in mind that the variable 'display_info' is currently referring to 'wrapper_function' which is the uninvoked function inside decorator_function waiting to be invoked

Finally, when display_info('John', 25) is invoked, wrapper_function is actually being called, since we called display_info with two positional arguments ('John' and 25) hence the need for wrapper_function(*args,**kwargs)

Hope that helps